# Permission denied при 777

Tags: linux, permissions

Бьюсь над проблемой уже несколько часов и никак не пойму где ошибка.

```
root@linux:~# ls -l /root
drwxrwsrwx  5 www-data www-data   4096 Nov 18 20:09 shop_v2

root@linux:~# sudo -u www-data stat /root/shop_v2
stat: cannot stat '/root/shop_v2': Permission denied
```

Пользователь www-data не может получить доступ к /root/shop_v2.

Права установил 777, но результата нет. Permission denied. Умные люди, подскажите в чем проблема :)

Comment: Очевидно, к каталогу /root доступа нет (и давать его ни в коем случае не нужно, умные люди не станут держать публичные данные в /root и уж тем более не будут пускать пользователя www-data читать файлы администратора системы)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что root является особым каталогом, доступ к которому имеет только суперюзер и никакие chmod 777 не решают это?

Comment: Он не является особым в техническом смысле, только вот делать chmod 777 на него всё равно не надо (и вообще делать chmod 777 нигде и никогда не надо, это лишь показывает ваше непонимание юниксовой системы прав доступа)

Comment: Посмотрите права на сам /root. Какого-нибудь `chmod o+x /root` должно хватить. Но почему вы выбрали этот каталог для сервера?

Comment: @vp_arth, drwx------ 12 root root  4096 Nov 18 21:55 root

Comment: Вот видите, у www-data нет прав на чтение/листинг директории)

Comment: Я думал если я обращаюсь к /root/public, то учитываются права только этой директории, а не всех директорий в пути

Comment: @CatGrey, чтобы по файловой системе найти иноду "public", нужно вначале найти иноду root и прочитать его содержимое (в этой иноде указаны все дочерние иноды, в том числе public). А чтение root запрещено аттрибутами. Вот так это работает, все на уровне организации файловой системы и работы с ней ядра.

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо всем!